# Missing scott user in Oracle 11 g database

Tags: installation, oracle-11g

I have installed Oracle 11g R2 on my Windows. During the installation, in password management, the "scott" user is missing. I'm unable to login in "scott" as my sample schema.

What do I have to do in order to get the "scott" user in my database?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have not unlocked your `scott user account` while installation,please follow the steps below to unlock you scott account .

When you started installing oracle ,it asked for `global database name` and `database password` that password is used for the `sys system sysman dbsnmp account`.

1. SQL> conn user/password;

   SQL> conn scott/tiger;

Error message is displayed: the account is locked.

2. Try to login as `"system"`  - pass

   `SQL> conn  system/password;`
3. Unlock "scott"

   `SQL> alter user scott account unlock;`
4. Can change `"tiger"`:

   `SQL> alter user scott identified by tiger;`
5. SQL> conn scott/tiger;    -Success

`scott account` is locked in 11g due to security thinking,

Now you can type `Connection Name :ORCL` ,`username:Scott`,`password:tiger` to login

Answer (score 0):

It may already be there (if you installed the demo schema) but locked for security reasons.

Log in as SYSTEM or SYS.

SQL > alter user scott account unlock;